# Where am I doing it wrong: CursorAdapter and Listview

Tags: android, listview

My first app.

When I click on row 1's Button I expect it to Hide `TextView` for that particular row. It does that BUT when i scroll down I see it has hidden other `TextView's too. I read a bit and found that this is expect as recycling takes place.

Now, I am wondering how to make sure that only particular row's `TextView` is hidden when its Button is clicked. I may have many rows as much as 7000+

Below is `CursorAdapter` code:

```
public class ToDoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public ToDoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

// The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
// you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    final TextView engText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.engText);
   final TextView arabText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.arabText);
    final TextView refText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.refText);
    Button buttonIA = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonIA); //For Arabic Text
    Button buttonIR = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonIR); //For Ref Text

    String arabic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainArab_Text"));
    String english = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainEng_Text"));
    String ref = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("REF"));

    arabText.setText(arabic.trim().replaceAll(" +", " "));
    engText.setText(english.replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", "TWOFEEDS").replaceAll("\n", " ").replaceAll(" +", " ").replaceAll("<br/>", "\n").replaceAll("TWOFEEDS", "\n"));
    refText.setText(ref.trim().replaceAll(" +", " "));
    arabText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    engText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    buttonIA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                { @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        arabText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                });

    buttonIR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                { @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    refText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Log.d("MYTAG", "INSIDE2");
                                }
                                });
    }
}
```

`Activity` code:

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
ListView listView ;
private SQLiteDatabase hadithlistDB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
    .....

    // Find ListView to populate
        ListView lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
// Setup cursor adapter using cursor from last step
        ToDoCursorAdapter todoAdapter = new ToDoCursorAdapter(this, todoCursor);
// Attach cursor adapter to the ListView
        lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);

        todoAdapter.changeCursor(todoCursor);
    }

}
```

**UPDATED**

Ok. I just inserted a debug comment/message in my app to see how this `CursorAdapter` works. When you scroll up and down it will show your row# or record number(in my case) in the debug comment.

So I came up with idea that I will tag all views as they are created and when I click on the Button on the row(say 1) that should hide my `TextView` on row 1 plus tag which is cursor position should be added to an array.

The logic that I have implemented so far does prevent other rows from being affected by the Button.

I clicked Button1 and it hid Textview1 on row 1. Then I scroll down to see if it affected any other rows, it hadn't. I scroll back up and see that Textview1 on row 1 is visible but on row 2 it is hidden.

Can anyone see what is wrong with this code:

```
public class ToDoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
List<Integer> selectedItemsPositions;//to store all selected items position

public ToDoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
    selectedItemsPositions = new ArrayList<>();

}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    //ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);

    rowView.setTag(cursor.getPosition());

    return rowView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    final TextView arabText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.arabText);
    final TextView engText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.engText);
    final TextView refText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.refText);

    Button buttonIA = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonIA); //For Arabic Text
    Button buttonIR = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonIR); //For Ref Text

    String arabic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainArab_Text"));
    String english = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainEng_Text"));
    String ref = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("REF"));

    arabText.setText(arabic.trim().replaceAll(" +", " "));
    engText.setText(english.replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", "TWOFEEDS").replaceAll("\n", " ").replaceAll(" +", " ").replaceAll("<br/>", "\n").replaceAll("TWOFEEDS", "\n"));
    refText.setText(ref.trim().replaceAll(" +", " "));

    view.setTag(cursor.getPosition());

    if(selectedItemsPositions.contains(cursor.getPosition())) {
        arabText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        arabText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    buttonIA.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
                    { @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();

                            if(selectedItemsPositions.contains(position)) {
                                arabText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                selectedItemsPositions.remove((Object) cursor.getPosition());
                            }
                            else {
                                arabText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Log.d("MYTAG", "CLICKE! INSIDE ELSE");
                                selectedItemsPositions.add( cursor.getPosition());
                            }
                        }
                    }
    );

    buttonIR.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
                { @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d("MYTAG", "INSIDE2");
                    }
                }
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by overriding the `getView` method to get the position value of the cell, using the `getPosition` of the cursor was a bit messy as it is updates with every `newView` call [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20053035/4944007), but still calling `getView` and `newView` will inflate the view twice (need some tweaking there)

here is the final code (This code resembles your other question, didn't have time to update it)

```
public class ToDoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
List<Integer> selectedArabTextItemsPositions;//to store all selected items position

Context context;
public ToDoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
    selectedArabTextItemsPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    this.context = context;
}

// The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
// you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_view_record, parent, false);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup arg2) {
    if (convertview == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_view_record,
                null);
    }
    convertview.setTag(position);
    return super.getView(position, convertview, arg2);
}



@Override
public void bindView(final View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    Log.d("TEST",String.valueOf((Integer) view.getTag()));

    final TextView arabText;
    final TextView engText;
    final TextView refText;
    final Button button;
    final Button button2;

    engText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.engText);
    arabText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.arabText);
    refText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.refText);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    String arabic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainArab_Text"));
    String english = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainEng_Text"));
    String ref = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("REF"));

    arabText.setText(arabic);
    engText.setText(english);
    refText.setText(ref);

    if(selectedArabTextItemsPositions.contains((Integer) view.getTag())) {
       arabText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        arabText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            if (selectedArabTextItemsPositions.contains((Integer) view.getTag())){
                arabText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d("selected contain id>>>>>>>>",String.valueOf(String.valueOf((Integer) view.getTag())));
                removeItemFromList((Integer) view.getTag(),selectedArabTextItemsPositions);
            }else {
                arabText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d("selected text does not contain id>>>>>>>>",String.valueOf((Integer) view.getTag()));
                selectedArabTextItemsPositions.add((Integer) view.getTag());
            }
            Log.d("LIST Content >>>>",String.valueOf(selectedArabTextItemsPositions));
        }

    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //viewHolder.engText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

void removeItemFromList (int object,List arrayList){
    Iterator<Integer> it = arrayList.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (it.next() == object) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have to save state of each row/item. I am not sure how it is done with `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: I fixed it by declaring position variable as `final` before 'if..else` in `bindView` and then used that same variable inside `onClick()` instead of using `cursor.getPosition()` again. 

like this 

'final Integer position= cursor.getPosition()`


Thank you for your response.